# How to run build/release pipeline using Azure DevOps REST API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to run new build pipeline through azure alert webhook. I'm looking for Azure DevOps REST API for this action. I didn't get the proper examples for running  the pipeline using REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Azure Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), you dont have any rest api to trigger a azure devops build. By using rest api you can perform the below azure devops build operations only.

[image]

Comment: Isnt the "Queue Build" API what the OP needs?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by trigger you mean you want to start a build, try the Queue API call listed in VenkateshDodda-MT's answer. It queus a new build.

Comment: I hope you dont mind me using this to ask, how does one set a variable at queue time via the REST API? The docs have the APIs to queue the build but dont have examples nor do they have the JSON body needed just to queue the build through that API which is of type POST :(